# ASP.NET MVC render view from string to generete report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

The problem is: the plataform generate reports for the clients. But each client what the same information in report, but with a diferent layout.
I don't want to produce the partial views, recompiling and publish the solution, each time the client want to change the layout.

I want to store in datastore a string that represent the partial view (report), and in runtime pass to the view with the model and render it.

I've looking for some solutions, but involve have the partial view file.
The article (http://www.umbraworks.net/bl0g/rebuildall/2009/11/17/ASP_NET_MVC_and_virtual_views) give an ideia, but in this case always clients access in the same URL (like ~/Reports/SomeReport/2, where the 2 is an id of an object owned by the client. The relationship between the client and the object is one client, many objects).

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Moving comment around RazorEngine to the answer as that seems to be more relevant.

For a dynamic template (e.g. where the template content is retrieved from a database and then bound to a model) it looks like [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) is applicable for this use case.

---

**Rending Raw HTML**
[nkvu - just leaving here for historical purposes as the "original", incorrect response leading to the correct response]

If you have a HTML string which you just want to display on the screen then you can use [`Html.Raw()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). Here is an old [example](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/using-html-raw-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/) but it should illustrate how Raw() works. Sorry if I've misunderstood your use case.

But as good practice you should ensure that you test/defend against various injection attacks which could arise because you're straight-rendering the HTML. I will try to find some links for you to consider & update this response when I do

Comment: Thanks for your idea. But I failed in the instructions.
The view have an model associated, with data from database. The HTML isn't static.
I want to pass the model to the view and render it. The view (layout) can be changed.

Comment: Ah OK, I think I understand better. Perhaps something like [this](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) project could help you with the view/template string being retrieved from the database? (in the examples I have seen they just initialise it in code for simplicity, but no reason the template string couldn't come from a database)